# CKEDITOR getData() returns html character entities (unicode), but how does one get untranslated characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Using CKEDITOR and its getData() method, I retrieve html character entities (unicode). How do you re-translate to the original code. I don't want to save unicode in my database. Or do you?

I made a test and outputing it from the DB into an HTML page results - as assumed - in every character of the unicode charachter set to be printed: e.g. `&oulm;` instead of `ö`. So the user gets HTML character entities displayed.

Any clue how I can decode it before I send it into my database? I glady do it with jQuery if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [`config.entities_latin`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities_latin) and [`config.entities_greek`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities_greek) to `false`.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'foo', {
    entities_latin: false,
    entities_greek: false
} );
```

Comment: ah. I see. only two that are configurable. (you answer as if you were a CKEDITOR developer) great help. Thank you Reinmar.

Comment: I'm a CKEditor developer :D I included `entities_greek`, because if you don't want latin characters to be encoded, you may also not want greek ones.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work 4.4.7. I have some html in an attribute and the & gets encoded to &amp; regardless

Comment: Because `&` is part of http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-basicEntities and it is recommended to leave the default value.